# Creating numpy linspace out of datetime

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib

I'm writing a script that plots some data with dates on the x axis (in matplotlib). I need to create a `numpy.linspace` out of those dates in order  to create a spline afterwards. Is it possible to do that?

What I've tried:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

dates = [
    datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 0, 31, 41),
    datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 1, 35),
    datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 2, 37, 9),
    datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 3, 59, 16),
    datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 5, 2, 23)
]

x = np.linspace(min(dates), max(dates), 500)
```

It throws this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'
```

I've also tried converting `datetime` to `np.datetime64`, but that doesn't work as well:

```
dates = [np.datetime64(i) for i in dates]
x = np.linspace(min(dates), max(dates), 500)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: ufunc multiply cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[us]') and dtype('float64')
```

Comment: There's a `numpy` wrapper of `datetime`, `np.datetime64` (I think) that might work.

Comment: Already tried that, it's in the question

Comment: I have opened a feature request for this in numpy here, and will update this post if/when it gets merged: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/21332

Comment: We astronomers use a type of date format called JD. And it's a floating point number. You can use Unix time too to create numbers and then convert them to datetime format. Maybe?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

##### Update - 2022

As pointed out by @Joooeey and @Ehtesh Choudhury, `pandas` now has [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), which makes creating `numpy.linspace`-like time series much simpler.

```
t = pd.date_range(
    start='2022-03-10',
    end='2022-03-15',
    periods=5
)
```

If it's important to have this time series as a `numpy` array, simply

```
>>> t.values

array(['2022-03-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2022-03-11T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2022-03-12T12:00:00.000000000', '2022-03-13T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2022-03-15T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

---

##### Original answer

Have you considered using `pandas`? Using an approach from [this possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796030/how-can-i-use-pandas-date-range-to-obtain-a-time-series-with-n-specified-perio?rq=1), you can make use of `np.linspace` in the following way

```
import pandas as pd

start = pd.Timestamp('2015-07-01')
end = pd.Timestamp('2015-08-01')
t = np.linspace(start.value, end.value, 100)
t = pd.to_datetime(t)
```

To obtain an `np.array` of the linear timeseries

```
In [3]: np.asarray(t)
Out[3]: 
array(['2015-06-30T17:00:00.000000000-0700',
       '2015-07-01T00:30:54.545454592-0700',
       '2015-07-01T08:01:49.090909184-0700',
               ...
       '2015-07-31T01:58:10.909090816-0700',
       '2015-07-31T09:29:05.454545408-0700',
       '2015-07-31T17:00:00.000000000-0700'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: Wanted to add a slightly simpler solution using [pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html): `t = pd.date_range('2015-07-01', '2015-08-01', periods=100)`

Answer (score 22):

As of pandas 0.23 you can use [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html):

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.date_range(min(dates), max(dates), periods=500).to_pydatetime()
```

Comment: Note that this creates a numpy array with dtype `object` containing Python `datetime` objects.  To get a numpy array with dtype `datetime64`, you want to use `.to_numpy()` instead of `to_pydatetime()`.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, np.linspace does not support datetime objects. But perhaps we can make our own function which roughly simulates it:

```
def date_linspace(start, end, steps):
  delta = (end - start) / steps
  increments = range(0, steps) * np.array([delta]*steps)
  return start + increments
```

This should give you an np.array with dates going from `start` to `end` in `steps` steps (not including the end date, can be easily modified).

Comment: delta can be imprecise, and when added up, the imprecision causes the end value returned to not match the end value passed in by a wide margin when dealing with small time values.

Comment: to include the end date, roughly equivalent to np.linspace's `endpoint=True`, I added an `endpoint=True` argument and used the lines `divisor = (steps-1) if endpoint else steps` and `delta = (end - start) / divisor`

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy # 1.15   

start = numpy.datetime64('2001-01-01')
end = numpy.datetime64('2019-01-01')

# Linspace in days:

days = numpy.linspace(start.astype('f8'), end.astype('f8'), dtype='<M8[D]')

# Linspace in milliseconds

MS1D = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
daytimes = numpy.linspace(start.astype('f8') * MS1D, end.astype('f8') * MS1D, dtype='<M8[ms]')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Pleast take some time to read [answer]. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The last error is telling us that `np.datetime` objects cannot multiply.  Addition has been defined - you can add `n` timesteps to a date and get another date.  But it doesn't make any sense to multiply a date.

```
In [1238]: x=np.array([1000],dtype='datetime64[s]')

In [1239]: x
Out[1239]: array(['1970-01-01T00:16:40'], dtype='datetime64[s]')

In [1240]: x[0]*3
...
TypeError: ufunc multiply cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[s]') and dtype('int32')
```

So the simple way to generate a range of datetime objects is to add range of timesteps.  Here, for example, I'm using 10 second increments

```
In [1241]: x[0]+np.arange(0,60,10)
Out[1241]: 
array(['1970-01-01T00:16:40', '1970-01-01T00:16:50', '1970-01-01T00:17:00',
       '1970-01-01T00:17:10', '1970-01-01T00:17:20', '1970-01-01T00:17:30'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

The error in `linspace` is the result of it trying to multiply the `start` by `1.`, as seen in the full error stack:

```
In [1244]: np.linspace(x[0],x[-1],10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1244-6e50603c0c4e> in <module>()
----> 1 np.linspace(x[0],x[-1],10)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype)
     88 
     89     # Convert float/complex array scalars to float, gh-3504
---> 90     start = start * 1.
     91     stop = stop * 1.
     92 

TypeError: ufunc multiply cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[s]') and dtype('float64')
```

Despite the comment it looks like it's just converting ints to float.  Anyways it wasn't written with `datetime64` objects in mind.

`user89161's` is the way to go if you want to use the `linspace` syntax, otherwise you can just add the increments of your choosen size to the start date.

`arange` works with these dates:

```
In [1256]: np.arange(x[0],x[0]+60,10)
Out[1256]: 
array(['1970-01-01T00:16:40', '1970-01-01T00:16:50', '1970-01-01T00:17:00',
       '1970-01-01T00:17:10', '1970-01-01T00:17:20', '1970-01-01T00:17:30'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```