# How to modify elements in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

here is my code:

```
a=np.arange('2017-01-01', '2017-01-09', dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

I got the following output:

```
array(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04',
       '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-08'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

I want to strip out the years from each element. How can I do that?

Comment: What does this mean? The datetimes are essentially epoch timestamps it doesn't make any sense to strip out the year. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The link asks about using dates in `linspace`. No mention of that function here. The link is about a range of dates, but that's all. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37964100

Answer (score 1):

The dates in `Y` units is:

```
In [870]: a.astype('datetime64[Y]')
Out[870]: array(['2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017'], dtype='datetime64[Y]')
```

Or subtracting the first date from the rest, gives a `timedelta64`

```
In [875]: a-a[0]
Out[875]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
```

`tolist` converts the array of dates to a list of `datetime` objects

```
In [888]: a.tolist()
Out[888]: 
[datetime.date(2017, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2017, 1, 2),
 datetime.date(2017, 1, 3),
 datetime.date(2017, 1, 4),
 datetime.date(2017, 1, 5),
 datetime.date(2017, 1, 6),
 datetime.date(2017, 1, 7),
 datetime.date(2017, 1, 8)]
```

Which can be formated as strings

```
In [889]: [x.strftime('%m-%d') for x in a.tolist()]
Out[889]: ['01-01', '01-02', '01-03', '01-04', '01-05', '01-06', '01-07', '01-08']
```

There's no `datetime64` format that consists of just month and date.

`tolist` or `item` on a `timedelta64[...]' produces a`datetime.timedelta` object.