# How to divide years in half a year in python?

Tags: python

How should I do to divide years in half a year in this case if running in Python code?

[image: The start year is 2020-05-15 and the final year is 2030-05-15.]

Comment: What is half a year?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects ?

Comment: I mean divide the whole years by 6 months

Comment: Not clear what you are having a problem with. Please read [mre]. .. Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Briefly, if the year starts from 2020-01-01 to 2021-12-31, what I want to do is to divide it into four time periods and list them as dataframes. Are there any functions can do that in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image] [image]

I wasn't sure if you wanted horizontal or vertical divisions so I gave you both.

More practically, maybe this answer will help?
[Creating numpy linspace out of datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964100/creating-numpy-linspace-out-of-datetime)

You can specify start and end date and the number of divisions.

Comment: Thanks for help. I solved it by using "date_range"