# How can I smoothen a line chart in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I've tried everything and looked in other threads here but I can't find how to smoothen a line in a matplotlib chart. The thing is that on most tutorials, both axis have numeric values, while in my case, for my x axis I have a date value...

Is this possible? If not, is there any other visualization library that could allow me to do this?

Here is my code:

```
date = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]
value = [4,12,15,7,25]
plt.plot(date,value)

plt.show()
```

Which is currently outputting this:

[image]

I want to show it like this:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot smooth line with PyPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283649/plot-smooth-line-with-pyplot)

Comment: No :( maybe i'm a little bit stupid, but that's one of the threads i've tried. Since my X values are qualitative (dates), the code is giving me this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Jan'

Comment: You could perhaps convert the Months to Numbers first? Also this question does not seem to about pandas so I have removed the tag. If there is a pandas aspect to this question please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68087386/edit) your question to reflect this and add the tag back.

Comment: Maybe run some code on the data that creates points in between each data point and therefore smooths it out.

Comment: How can I convert them to numbers? I need the x axis labels to remain with text :S

Comment: You can use just the numbers `0, 1, 2, ...` for the spline function.  E.g. `date_num=np.arange(len(date))`.  And after drawing the curve call `plt.xticks(date_num, date)``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I retracted my close vote because I missed the issue that you are plotting against strings on the x-axis (and thus it is more difficult to interpolate between them).  As others have suggested, the key then is to use your date-strings to source numbers for plotting and interpolating.  Once you have done so, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5284038/13386979) is still a good framework to follow.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

# original data
date = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]
value = [4,12,15,7,25]

# create integers from strings
idx = range(len(date))
xnew = np.linspace(min(idx), max(idx), 300)

# interpolation
spl = make_interp_spline(idx, value, k=3)
smooth = spl(xnew)

# plotting, and tick replacement
plt.plot(xnew, smooth)
plt.xticks(idx, date)
```

[image]

`idx` is the values `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, and it is used for plotting and interpolation.  At the end, the call to `xticks` is used to use the date strings to label those tick positions.

The above is mainly based on the comments (from [HenryEcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker) and [JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc)).  The new piece I wanted to add is that another way of doing the interpolation is to convert your strings to actual date-times:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates # for formatting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
import pandas as pd # for working with dates

# instead of ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"], create datetime objects
date = pd.date_range('01-01-2020', freq='MS', periods=5)
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')

value = [4,12,15,7,25]

# now make new x positions using a date range, instead of linspace 
# see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50728640/13386979
xnew = pd.date_range(date.min(), date.max(), periods=300)

# interpolation
spl = make_interp_spline(date, value, k=3)
smooth = spl(xnew)

# plotting
plt.plot(xnew, smooth)

# using mdates to get the x-axis formatted correctly
months = mdates.MonthLocator()
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b') # %b -> Month as locale’s abbreviated name
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
```

[image]

This latter approach involves a little extra formatting work (and imports), but it is a little more explicit about plotting temporal data.  I find this can be more intuitive to work with.  For example, if you have multiple time series you can easily plot them side-by-side; you can refer to specific dates more easily in the code; you don't have to remember what indices refer to which dates (e.g. March and `2` in this example), etc...