# How to use xticks and marker functions for smooth line graph - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, spline, xticks

I make a line graph more smooth by applying the following lines of code (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68087386/how-can-i-smoothen-a-line-chart-in-matplotlib)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline



#create random data
years = list(range(1998, 2021, 1))
print(len(years)) #23
random_values = [86, 78, 63, 56, 100, 72, 59, 71, 84, 89, 62, 57, 56, 73, 92, 52, 77, 60, 84, 64, 86, 80, 59]

idx = range(len(years))
xnew = np.linspace(min(idx), max(idx), 300)

# interpolation
spl = make_interp_spline(idx, random_values, k=3)
smooth = spl(xnew)

# plotting, and tick replacement
plt.plot(xnew, smooth, color = 'black', marker = '.')
plt.xticks(idx, years)

plt.show()
```

which shows:
[image]

Based on this figure, I have 2 questions:

1. How can I limit the number of ticks on the x-axis, so that only the years 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, and 2020 are visualized? - what makes it potentially more difficult is that two arguments are given for `plt.xticks()`
2. How can I limit the number of marker points so that it matches the number of years and its related positions (so having 23 marker points eventually)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. First you remove the marker for the spline plot, next you add a scatter plot to show the desired markers.

```
plt.plot(xnew, smooth, color = 'black', marker = '')
plt.scatter(idx, random_values, color = 'black', marker = '.')
xtickYears = list(range(2000, 2021, 5))
plt.xticks([years.index(i) for i in xtickYears], xtickYears)
```

Comment: Your suggestion for the labeling works well so my first question is answered.

Comment: @FoekeBoersma I misunderstood the question the first time. The answer is edited.